# Using named scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I have a schedule model having **start time as date time** and **duration in minutes as integer**.

Using named scope is there a way I can get the records having `(start_time + duration) < current_time` ?

Comment: The MYSQL condition needs to be something like  WHERE (ADDTIME(scheduled_start_time, duration_in_min) < '2011-03-29 06:55:02'). But if the duration is 123 ie 123 minutes, instead of taking this as 2hr and 3 minutes... it adds a 1 min 23 sec to the scheduled_start_time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might implement what you asked for with SQL level date manipulation functions, like [mysql's DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
scope :not_over, where('DATE_ADD(start_time, INTERVAL duration MINUTE) > UTC_TIMESTAMP()')
```

Though if performance is a consideration, you might want to precalculate an 'end_time' column and add an index on it.

Comment: in my table the start_time is in date time format and duration is in integer

Comment: Oh, sorry, there should be some database-specific answer, let me look

Comment: You should use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` instead of `NOW()`